# Python: Change the parameter of the loop while the loop is running

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to change a in the for-loop to [4,5,6].
This code just print: 1, 2, 3

```
a = [1,2,3]

for i in a:
    global a
    a = [4,5,6]
    print i
```

I want the ouput `1, 4, 5, 6`.

Comment: What's the real use case (rather than this toy problem)?

Comment: With the new edit, it makes even less sense than before...

Comment: `a` is a link on a website. The programm goes to this website. Then it will set new links (4,5,6). If some condition is true, on of the links is choosen, and it is starting again. (Maybe you know 'getting to philosophy' on Wikipedia). `a` changes the whole time.

Comment: @kame - Are you trying to recurse all the links in a site?

Comment: Is this recursion? Maybe yes. I want to go from some website to the next and so on. But I choose only one link.

Comment: You should use python lists. And do the loop until the list is empty. When you visit a link, remove it from the list.

Comment: So you don't need backtracking? Just follow one link after another?

Comment: No backtracking, just following the links.

Comment: You should delete this question and actually ask the one you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to clarify the question because there is no explanation of how you should derive the desired output 1, 4, 5, 6 when your input is [1, 2, 3].  The following produces the desired output, but it's completely ad-hoc and makes no sense:

```
i = 0
a = [1, 2, 3]
while i < len(a):
    print(a[i])
    if a[i] == 1:
        a = [4, 5, 6]
        i = 0          # edit - good catch larsmans
    else:
        i += 1
```

The main point is that you can't modify the parameters of a for loop while the loop is executing.  From the python documentation:

> It is not safe to modify the sequence being iterated over in the loop
>   (this can only happen for mutable sequence types, such as lists). If
>   you need to modify the list you are iterating over (for example, to
>   duplicate selected items) you must iterate over a copy.

Edit: if based on the comments you are trying to walk URLs, you need more complicated logic to do a depth-first or breadth-first walk than just replacing one list (the top-level links) with another list (links in the first page).  In your example you completely lose track of pages 2 and 3 after diving into page 1.

Comment: You'll want to reset `i=0` when resetting the list variable `a`. Otherwise, +1, since this seems to reflect the OP's actual problem, described in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the assignment

```
a = [4,5,6]
```

just changes the variable a, not the underlying object. There are various ways you could deal with this; one would be to use a while loop like

```
a = [1,2,3]

i = 0
while i<len(a):
    print a[i]
    a = [4,5,6]
    i += 1
```

prints

```
1
5
6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print id(a) at useful points in your code you'll realise why this doesn't work.

Even something like this does not work:

```
a = [1,2,3]

def change_a(new_val):
    a = new_val

for i in a:
    change_a([4,5,6])
    print i
```

I don't think it is possible to do what you want.  Break out of the current loop and start a new one with your new value of a.